# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando crear una tabla con campos referenciados a otra tabla, pero me sale *Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'ventas_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'productosservicios'*. Es la primera vez que trabajo en Mysql, no tengo conocimientos previos, solo estaba siguiendo un videotutorial. Estas son las tablas:

```
create database stylos;
show databases;
use stylos;
CREATE TABLE empleados (
    id int,
    estatus varchar (255),
    nombre varchar (255),
    cargo varchar (255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE empleados MODIFY COLUMN id int auto_increment;
ALTER TABLE empleados MODIFY COLUMN id int NOT NULL;

use stylos;
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    numeroDeCedula int,
    nombre varchar (255),
    fechaDeNacimiento date,
    numeroDeTelefono varchar (255),
    PRIMARY KEY (numeroDeCedula)
);

ALTER TABLE empleados MODIFY COLUMN id int auto_increment;
ALTER TABLE empleados MODIFY COLUMN id int NOT NULL;

use stylos;
CREATE TABLE productosServicios (
    id int,
    tipo varchar (32),
    nombre varchar (32) NOT NULL,
    precio decimal (9,2) NOT NULL,
    stock int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE productosServicios MODIFY COLUMN id int auto_increment;
ALTER TABLE productosServicios MODIFY COLUMN stock int;
ALTER TABLE productosServicios MODIFY COLUMN id int NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE productosServicios MODIFY COLUMN tipo varchar (32) NOT NULL;

use stylos;
CREATE TABLE ventas (
    idVenta int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    tipoServicio varchar (32),
    idServicio int,
    tipoProducto varchar (32),
    idProducto int,
    cliente varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    empleado varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    fecha date NOT NULL,
    total decimal (9,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idVenta),
    FOREIGN KEY(tipoServicio) references productosServicios(nombre),
    FOREIGN KEY(idServicio) references productosServicios(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(tipoProducto) references productosServicios(nombre),
    FOREIGN KEY(idProducto) references productosServicios(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(cliente) references clientes(nombre),
    FOREIGN KEY(empleado) references empleados(nombre),
    FOREIGN KEY(total) references productosServicios(precio),
);
```

Comment: MySQL requiere índices sobre llaves foráneas. Haz `productosServicios.id` llave primaria y agrega índices para `productosServicios.nombre` y `productosServicios.precio`.

Answer (score 0):

Además de los índices que te indican en los comentarios, que puedes crear así:

```
ALTER TABLE productosServicios ADD INDEX(nombre);
ALTER TABLE clientes ADD INDEX(nombre);
ALTER TABLE empleados ADD INDEX(nombre);
ALTER TABLE productosServicios ADD INDEX(precio);
```

También te sobra una `,` justo en la última `FK` que intentas crear.